# Implementing Linked List in an array

Tags: linked-list, time-complexity

Implementing Linked List in an array

[image]

As far as i understand:

1. Deletion will be done in O(1) time as we will just move front pointer,but reverse will take O(n) time. Please correct me if i am understanding it wrong.

Comment: explain how you have come to this conclusion!

Comment: Deletion:- It will be simply deleting kth element from array,however i am not sure whether i should be shifting the array after deletion,that would be 0(n) itherwise.

Comment: Reversing :- If i have array and in that if i change front and rear pointer addresses,then i think it can be reversed,but here again we need to traverse the list in reverse direction instead of forward.Hope my point is clear

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned delete can be done in constant time, a doubly linked list with head and tail pointers can be reversed in O(1) time by swapping head and tail pointers. Here P is the first element and last pointer is (first element + list size) mod n , this means

1. first element a has pointers to itself and last element
2. second element a has pointer to itself and the element before first element    which is first element
3. 3rd element has pointer to itself and second element

and so on , so by swapping first and last pointer you can reverse the list in O(1)

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying about pointers swapping.These are implemented in array so there are no pointers in a node pointing to itself and next elements.Only 2 pointers/variables First and last are used to access array

Comment: you have a circular array and pointer to first and last element right, if you shift one step from first to second element using provided formula for calculating last you will get the previous element . Sure those two are variables but the relation between two variable is provided, I assume